# Is it possible to create custom availability for a period of time in a bookings service using graph api?

Tags: graph, service, availability

I am trying to create custom availability for a certain period of time in a bookings service. The service is unavailable out of those periods. Is there any way to do that using the graph api?
This is a screenshot of bookings:

[image]